# Reverse for 'data' with arguments '(1,)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found

Tags: python, django

I am new to Django. I am trying to make a simple web app which contains some name of stocks then you have to click on one then next window will be of what data you want like "Get percentage change" and then it will show the percentage change in that stock. I know some part of code should be better but I am just trying different parts of Django. I am getting problem in second part, after selecting stock, I am getting error and I have tried my best but not able to remove it.

This is my urls.py file:

```
# project/stocks.urls.py
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url

from stocks import views

urlpatterns = patterns('',
   url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
   url(r'^(?P<stocks_id>\d+)/$', views.choice, name='choice'),
   url(r'^(?P<stocks_id>\d+)/(?P<choice_id>\d+)/$', views.data, name='data')
)
```

This is my views file:

```
# project/stocks.views.py
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template import RequestContext, loader
from stocks.models import Stocks, DataChoice
from NewStock_API import Get_Quote, Get_percent_change
from django.views import generic


def index(request):
    latest_stocks = Stocks.objects.all()
    context = {'latest_stocks': latest_stocks}
    return render(request, 'stocks/index.html', context)


def choice(request, stocks_id):
    total_choice = DataChoice.objects.all()
    context = {'total_choice': total_choice}
    return render(request, 'stocks/choice.html', context)


def data(request, stocks_id, choice_id):
    selected_stock = Stocks.objects.get(id=stocks_id)
    selected_symbol = selected_stock.symbol
    stocks = Get_Quote(selected_symbol)
    return render(request, 'stocks/data.html', {'stocks': stocks})
```

This is my models file:

```
# project/stocks.models.py
from django.db import models


class Stocks(models.Model):
    symbol = models.CharField(max_length=20)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.symbol


class DataChoice(models.Model):
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=20)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.choice_text
```

The error I am getting is:

> Error during template rendering
>
> In template /home/mukesh/markets/stocks/templates/stocks/choice.html, error at line 3
>   Reverse for 'data' with arguments '(1,)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried:

```
[u'stocks/(?P<stocks_id>\\d+)/(?P<choice_id>\\d+)/$']
```

My choice.html file is:

```
<ul>
    {% for choice in total_choice %}
    <li><a href="{% url 'stocks:data' choice.id %}">{{ choice.choice_text }}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your data url pattern takes two arguments a stock id and a choice id; you are only supplying one.

You need to supply both, like this:

```
{% url 'stocks:data' stocks_id=stocks.id choice_id=choice.id %}
```

Comment: Ok so you mean, I should change the third line of my "choice.html" by the one you have written? sorry for my lack of understanding, pardon me as a newbie.

Comment: I have tried changing my third line of "choice.html" with yours but it is not working.

Comment: Well it won't work unless you actually have a variable in your template context called `stocks.id` - you need to pass this in from your view.